# How to open a new window in C++ in Carbon on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos-carbon

I did not find a documentation, so I would like to have the code equivalent to:

```
#include <carbon.h>

int main() {
    carbon::Window win1 = carbon::openWindow(10,10,640,480);
    win1.setVisible(true);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, with researches on google and Stack Overflow I did NOT find the elements necessary to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent to"? What's wrong with the code as written?

Comment: My code will not compile because this is not these functions and i don't know the namespaces and function names to do that because there is no documentation that i found to do that.

Comment: @CrearoLisifi Probable reason why you didn't find any documentation is that entire Carbon API was deprecated in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

> the problem is that with researches in google and stack overflow i did NOT find the elements necessary to do that

Carbon is an old framework intended to help developers transition from classic MacOS (i.e. versions 9.x and lower) to MacOS X. As Algirdas Preidžius points out in a comment, `HIToolbox.framework`, which is the part of Carbon that you'd use to create windows and such, was [deprecated in MacOS X 10.7](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH210-BBCFGHBB). There's little point in trying to use those frameworks now.

Putting that aside, your example illustrates a basic misunderstanding of what's required of a program with a graphical user interface. Here's your code:

```
int main() {
carbon::Window win1 = carbon::openWindow(10,10,640,480);
win1.setVisible(true);
return 0;
}
```

Even if the Carbon API happened to match what you have here (it's not even close), your program would appear to do nothing. It would create a window and perhaps display it, but then it would exit immediately, so that the window would likely never appear on the screen at all, or might flash on the screen and disappear so fast that you probably wouldn't see it. Programs with a graphical interface spend nearly all of their time waiting for the user to do something, like move the mouse or press the mouse button or press a key on the keyboard or insert a floppy disk (remember, we're talking old school here). To facilitate that, the heart of any GUI application is the *event loop*. In the early days before it was even called "MacOS", the Macintosh operating system could only run one program at a time, and that program had to poll the OS to get each new event, so the heart of the application looked something like this:

```
EventRecord theEvent;
EventMask eventMask = everyEvent;
while (!quitting) {
    GetNextEvent(eventMask, &eventRecord);
    switch (eventRecord.what) {
        case keyDown: {
            // do something with the key in the event
        }
        case keyUp: {
            // do something with the key in the event
        }
        case autoKey: {
            // do something with the key in the event
        }
        case mouseDown: {
            // do something with the mouse position in the event
        }
        case mouseUp: {
            // do something with the mouse position in the event
        }
        // ...and so on...
    }
}
```

That was the *event loop*. In later versions, the OS changed to allow multiple apps to run at the same time, so the event loop was based around a function called `WaitNextEvent()` instead of `GetNextEvent()`, the main difference being that WNE would block if no events were available. When Carbon came along, the style changed again -- this time the event loop was handled by the operating system, and programs would simply register callback functions for all the events they were interested in (which is pretty much how Microsoft Windows apps also work), and those handlers would get called as they were needed.

All of this is really just to explain that there's a lot more to a GUI app than what you've indicated -- you don't just create a window, you have to also take care of it. Your intent isn't clear from your question, but whatever you're trying to do, Carbon is almost certainly not the answer. If you want to create a basic application, creating a new macOS project in Xcode will give you everything you need. If you want to use C++ in your application, know that you can mix C++ with Objective-C pretty easily, and integrating with Swift code should also be pretty straightforward.